# When i open uploaded file form into edit , file name can not come in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file-upload, upload

I am creating form with the file upload , it is upload successfully but when i open it in to the edit in the view part file name does not come, It shows no file chosen whereas i inspect them, value as filename comes

I can not able to find why it whould not come in view part.Please can any one help me

Thank you

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
       <%= f.file_field :attachment, class: "btn btn-large btn-default btn-file custom-file-input", :disabled => @disabled_field, :accept => ".png,.jpg,.jpeg", :style => "margin-left: 20px;", value: @t_shyain.try(:attachment_file_name) %>
</div>

when inspect it shows as

<input class="btn btn-large btn-default btn-file custom-file-input"  accept=".png,.jpg,.jpeg" style="margin-left: 20px;" value="Desert.jpg" type="file" name="t_shyain[attachment]">
```

store in to database as

t.attachment : attachment

controller

```rb
def new
    @t_shyain = TShyain.new
end

def edit
end
```

Comment: Its a default behaviour of the file upload. Add new label and show the filename. Or you can also preview that file.

Answer (score 0):

Hello @Rinkal You can not see file name in edit form.

It always show 'No file chosen'. Instead of this you can display file name in label or you can display preview for file.